# Assign display value from a combo box to another text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I am having code to display combo box such as

```
da.Fill(ds1, "HDTYPE");
comboHD.DisplayMember = "hw_define";
comboHD.ValueMember = "hwd_Id";
comboHD.DataSource = ds1.Tables["HDTYPE"];
```

The problem is I want to assign the selected text ie, `hw_define` to another text field for printing the data and `hwd_Id` to database for saving the data. I'm able to get the selected ID(`hwd_id`) by using `hwtype.SelectedValue`.
But how can I get selected - `hw_define` text to assign another text box?

Comment: on selectedIndex on comboHD set textbox value

Comment: `comboHD.Text` should do it.

Comment: Thank you @Irshad, It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `comboHD.Text` to get he value displayed in the combo box.